# React + Vite : Build process interfering with widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, bundler

I am making a football app (react + vite) like Fotmob and I am using api-football for the API data. I am trying to integrate their widget in my app.

The widget works fine when used in the index.html (static asset) file. While when I place the widget in my react component nothing shows up.

Widget =

```
<div id="wg-api-football-standings"
    data-host="v3.football.api-sports.io"
    data-key="api_key"
    data-league="39"
    data-team=""
    data-season="2021"
    data-theme=""
    data-show-errors="false"
    data-show-logos="true"
    class="wg_loader">
</div>
<script
    type="module"
    src="https://widgets.api-sports.io/2.0.3/widgets.js">
</script>
```

Using this in react app

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

export default function App(){
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        const myScript = document.createElement('script')
        
        myScript.src = 'https://widgets.api-sports.io/2.0.3/widgets.js'

        myScript.type = 'module'

        myScript.defer = true

        document.head.appendChild(myScript)
    },[])

    return(
        <div 
            id="wg-api-football-standings"
            data-host="v3.football.api-sports.io"
            data-key="api_key"
            data-league="39"
            data-team=""
            data-season="2023"
            data-theme=""
            data-show-errors="false"
            data-show-logos="true"
            className="wg_loader">
        </div>
    )

}
```

I have also tried placing only the `<script>` tag in index.html tag and  removed `useEffect` from the Widget component, but that also didn't solve the problem.

I have also tried the same procedure using webpack but no success.

I think the build process is creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

In React, the `useEffect` function only run after the View (UI) is rendered.
In your example, when placed the logic applying the script inside `useEffect` its will not trigger re-render so that the UI will not work.

You can try moving the script into HTML file and React only render JSX

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).